# Lambda How to reordering elements in list ascending order and place null value at the back?

Tags: c#, lambda

Says I have `ListA={null,3,2,null}`.

```
ListA.OrderBy(x=>x.ID) //would return me null,null,2,3
```

If my objective is to get `2,3,null,null`, currently I can only think of extracting out the null item, and manually pump into the back.

Is there a clean approach where it will return me `2,3,null,null`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use `OrderByDescending + ThenBy`(assuming that it's a`List<int?>`):

```
var orderedList = ListA
     .OrderByDescending(x => x.HasValue)
     .ThenBy(x => x);
```

`x.HasValue` returns `true` or `false` where `true` is higher than `false`. That's why i'm using `OrderByDescending`.

If you want to sort the original list i would use [`List.Sort`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w56d4y5z%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) with a custom `Compaison<T>` that treats `null` as highest value:

```
ListA.Sort((a1, a2) => (a1 ?? int.MaxValue).CompareTo(a2 ?? int.MaxValue));
```

This is more efficient since it doesn't need to create a new list.

Answer (score 2):

As an alternative to Tim's answer you could write your own `IComparer<T>` which does the custom sorting algorithm for you.

```
var array = list.OrderBy(x => x, new NullableIntComparer())
            .ToArray();

class NullableIntComparer : IComparer<int?>
{
    public int Compare(int? x, int? y)
    {
        if (x.HasValue && y.HasValue)
        {
            return x.Value.CompareTo(y.Value);
        }
        if (x.HasValue)
        {
            return -1;
        }
        if (y.HasValue)
        {
            return 1;
        }
        return 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: You can also use the overload of `List.Sort`: `ListA.Sort((a1, a2) => (a1 ?? int.MaxValue).CompareTo(a2 ?? int.MaxValue));`

Comment: @TimSchmelter If you don't have a `List<T>` and you're in .Net4.5 You can convert `Comparison` delegate tp `IComparer` using `Comparer<T>.Create(...`. btw your alternate option is beautiful+1, I don't think I'd come up with something like that :)

Answer (score 0):

Tried the following:

```
class Program
    {
        class A
        {
            public A(){}
            public int? ID { get; set; }
        }
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var listA = new List<A>
                {
                    new A(){ID = null},
                    new A(){ID = 2},
                    new A(){ID = null},
                    new A(){ID = 3},

                };

            var result = listA.OrderByDescending(x => x.ID != null).ThenBy(x => x.ID);

            foreach (var a in result)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(a.ID);
            }

        }
    }
```